# 'self' refers to the method 'EquationController.self', which may be unexpected

Tags: swift, macos, self

i tried to use lazy var but it didn't work, so i need to solve this cz the "Add Graph" button is not working:

```swift
var addGraphButton: NSButton = {
    let button = NSButton(title: "Add Graph", target: self, action: #selector (addGraph))
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return button // 'self' refers to the method 'EquationController.self', which may be unexpected
}()
```

[image: error]

Comment: Please paste in your actual code, instead of a screen shot of your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the context you posed, `self` refers to the `EquationController` type itself, not an object which is an instance of `EquationController`, which is what you intended.

I.e., `self.performSelector(#selector(addGraph))` would end up calling `class func addGraph`, *not* your instance method `func addGraph`.

To fix this, make the variable `lazy`, which will defer the instantiation of the button to where you first use it, at which point the initialization of `self` is complete. You cannot reference `self` of the instance in a closure-initialized stored property unless you make it `lazy`. E.g.:

```swift
lazy var addGraphButton: NSButton = {
    let button = NSButton(title: "Add Graph", target: self, action: #selector(addGraph))
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return button
}()
```

---

You said:

> i tried to use lazy var but it didn’t work

This is the correct solution. You did not share your `addGraph` implementation, but make sure you add `@objc` qualifier. E.g., you would generally define the action to take one parameter:

```swift
@objc func addGraph(_ sender: Any) { ... }
```

And then:

```swift
lazy var addGraphButton: NSButton = {
    let button = NSButton(title: "Add Graph", target: self, action: #selector(addGraph(_:)))
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return button
}()
```

Comment: Hey Rob, I added some context for what the problem is, prior to your solution to it. Are you okay with this edit? If not, I'll roll it back

Comment: No, that's fine. Thanks for asking, though!

Comment: thank you, Rob, the problem was that I used lazy var on button, not on addGraphButton. I'm still new to swift so I need your recommendation to learn the language more properly because it is still difficult for me to have a good understanding only from the documentation.

Comment: Yeah, going from the documentation alone is a tough way to learn. I’d suggest searching the web for online video recommendations. I might suggest posting that as a question here on Stack Overflow, but those sorts of recommendations are considered off topic and your question would quickly get down-voted and closed.

Comment: Ok, deal then I'll keep searching the web, thank you.